# Add/remove process from kernel runqueue

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel, scheduler

I am trying to add my own policy to the linux kernel scheduler.
every process has `int my_policy` in his `task_struct`, and my demand is that only the process with the highest policy can run at a time(process without policy set i.e `my_policy = -1` can run regularly).
I tried to add/remove process from the runqueue accordingly every `scheduler_tick()`, and most of the time it works, but the other time it gets stuck!

This is my code: (inside the scheduler_tick() function)

```
struct task_struct *it;
int max_policy = -1;

for_each_task(it) {
    if (it->my_policy != -1 && (it->state == TASK_RUNNING || (it->state == TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE && it->is_waiting_policy == 1))) {
        if (it->my_policy > max_policy)
            max_policy = it->my_policy;
    }
}

if (max_policy > -1) {
    for_each_task(it) {
        /* don't look at process without policy */
        if (it->my_policy == -1)
            continue;
        if (it->state == TASK_RUNNING && it->my_policy < max_policy) {
            it->is_waiting_policy = 1;
            it->state = TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE;
            deactivate_task(it, rq);
        } else if (it->state == TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE && it->is_waiting_policy == 1 && it->my_policy == max_policy) {
            it->is_waiting_policy = 0;
            it->state = TASK_RUNNING;
            activate_task(it, rq);
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, sometime it doesn't work :(
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an initialization of `max_policy= -1;` before the `for_each_task`.

Comment: all processes are initialized with `max_policy = -1` on default, changing `my_policy` is done explicitly when the process is running.

Comment: Gal, this is a function with a local variable `max_policy`, which is on the stack and which _must_ be initialized as it otherwise has an undefined value. Maybe this is not all the code, please show it.

Comment: You are right, post is edited with correct code.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your logic. I have written some assumptions around it that you can check. The logic seems OK and either the currently running process will continue to run, or another process will be activated to run, *however*, in your logic it is possible that a task is activated before the currently running task is deactivated. That occurrs when the task to activate is before the task to deactivate in the `for_each_task` loop. How will `activate_task` handle this?

The assumptions are:

- there is currently one process running (i.e. scheduled to use the CPU). (The logic lets this process continue to run if no other process has been determined to have a higher priority.)
- all other processes have `is_waiting_policy == 1`.
- `it->state` is `{TASK_RUNNING | TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE }`; there are no other states.

Comment: let me go over the assumptions:
- It's possible that only normal process(process with `my_policy = -1`) are currently running, that is not a problem. the demand that only process with highest policy will run applies to `my_policy != -1`

-when a process is taken out from the runqueue due to not having the highest policy, `is_waiting_policy` flag is set to 1.

-those are the states that interest me when scheduling. (in runqueue or can't run because of policy). other states will be taken care of by normal scheduler.

Why is that problem if another task is activated before other is deactivated?

Comment: I thought the problem might be when trying to deactivate a process that happens to be the `current` process. Not sure if this is the correct way to remove such a process. Any thoughts?

Comment: The question is, what the activation function does when it finds another process is still active. It might ignore the activation request.

Comment: As far as I understand the `activate_task()` function adds the specified process to the runqueue, not sure why this scenario should be a problem.
Somewhere in the future the scheduler will take this process from the runqueue and give it it's CPU time. It's not trying to take the `current` process time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "work" in "sometimes it doesn't work"?